Issue when trying to connect to my RPI5 whith ssh extention
Im trying to connect to my RPI5 with vscode remote ssh extention. But it does not work. I have tried to disable my firewall but that did not work. this is my log:
[16:17:18.436] Running script with connection command: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -L 127.0.0.1:65198:127.0.0.1:35865 "192.168.0.119" bash
[16:17:18.436] Spawning tunnel with: type "C:\Users\zamplex\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-linux-multi-line-command-192.168.0.119-378282458.sh" | "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -L 127.0.0.1:65198:127.0.0.1:35865 "192.168.0.119" bash
[16:17:18.436] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[16:17:18.437] > 
[16:17:18.630] > ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[16:17:18.872] > Connected to SSH Host - Please do not close this terminal
[16:17:18.872] Spawned SSH tunnel between local port 65198 and remote target port 35865
[16:17:18.872] Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
[16:17:18.874] Tunneled port 35865 to local port 65198
[16:17:18.874] Resolved "ssh-remote+192.168.0.119" to "port 65198"
[16:17:18.883] Initizing new exec server for ssh-remote+192.168.0.119
[16:17:18.883] Resolving exec server at port 65198
[16:19:33.672] Exec server for ssh-remote+192.168.0.119 failed: Error: read ECONNRESET
[16:19:33.673] Resolver error: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at Socket.<anonymous> (c:\Users\myusername\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1\out\extension.js:2:293965)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:632:26)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:529:35)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
[16:19:33.678] ------

[16:19:33.901] > channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
> channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
[16:19:33.975] Opening exec server for ssh-remote+192.168.0.119
[16:19:33.984] Initizing new exec server for ssh-remote+192.168.0.119
[16:19:33.985] Using commit id "b58957e67ee1e712cebf466b995adf4c5307b2bd" and quality "stable" for server
[16:19:33.988] Install and start server if needed ```

I have tried:
disabling my firewall
starting the remote server on my rpi5
deleting the vscode server on my rpi5 

